# Write in a TextView like its an EditText

Tags: android

I have a TextView element in a ListView. It should look like a regular text label with no curser visible etc., but it should go into edit mode when a button is clicked.

Im not using a regular EditText because the thing steals the clicks from the ListView its in.

So, how can I edit the TextView or prevent an EditText to steal clicks?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by 'edittext steals the clicks from the listview'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prevent it from stealing clicks by adding

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

to the `EditText` in the layout xml file

Comment: It helped partially. Now i can pick a list item if I click on a blank spot. If I click on the textfield, I see no reaction. Also I try to do this: edit.setFocusableInTouchMode(true); in my code. I get a softkeyboard but I cant enter any letters.

Comment: It seems that I can set the cursor in the textfield, the keyboard pops up, but then the cursor immediately disappears (keyboard stays up).

Comment: Alright, the keyboard sliding in changed my layout, and somehow that broke it. I set "adjustPan" in my manifest, now it works. Thanks for the hint.